# Facing library dependencies while installing krb5-server on RHEL 6.9

Tags: linux, kerberos, rhel, mapr

I am facing issues in " yum install krb5-server" on RHEL 6.9 .This I am doing to install Kerberos on MapR 5.2 cluster. Issue mentioned below:

```
[root@master ~]# yum install krb5-server


Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-server.x86_64 0:1.10.3-57.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-libs = 1.10.3-57.el6 for package: krb5-server-1.10.3-57.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-libs.i686 0:1.10.3-57.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux.so.1 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err.so.2 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.192.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
---> Package keyutils-libs.i686 0:1.4-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package libcom_err.i686 0:1.41.12-22.el6 will be installed
---> Package libselinux.i686 0:2.0.94-7.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-23.3.el6_8 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for krb5-libs which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of krb5-libs of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude krb5-libs.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of krb5-libs installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of krb5-libs installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686 != krb5-libs-1.10.3-65.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libcom_err-1.41.12-22.el6.i686 != libcom_err-1.41.12-23.el6.x86_64

[root@master ~]#
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yum errors like this happen if the system is installed from newer installation media and then subscribed to software channels which only provide older package versions.  I usually see it when people install the betas and then do not enable the beta channels after installation (which is a manual step).

The hint is in this line:

```
       Protected multilib versions: krb5-libs-1.10.3-57.el6.i686 != krb5-libs-1.10.3-65.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libcom_err-1.41.12-22.el6.i686 != libcom_err-1.41.12-23.el6.x86_64
```

Yum tries to install version 1.10.3-57.el6, while 1.10.3-65 is already installed.  (You can ignore the i686/x86_64 difference, yum goes *really* wrong while trying to figure out what to install here.)

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9 has been released, so it is not the usual beta problem.  You need to check the channel subscriptions with `yum repolist -v` and then use `subscription-manager repos --disable=… --enable=…` to fix the channel configuration.

If you use Satellite, the policy applied to your system might feed it the wrong version of the operating system.  In this case, you may have to make the changes in the Satellite infrastructure.

If, for some reason, you need an EUS version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (older than 6.9), you should just set up a new system with that.  Downgrades can be rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing yum cache, and then the retry it.

```
# yum clean all
```

or

```
# rm -rf /var/cache/yum

# yum update

# yum install krb5-server
```